# Showing a popup that depends on the authentication status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, popup

I'm trying the implement a page that some profiles are listed on card like components with their names, ids and pictures. In this page unregistered users are not allowed to see details of the profile, so I have to show them a popup to inform them a message like "If you want to see details you have to log in." I'm keeping authentication status in a variable for now just like "auth = true" or "auth = false".

If auth is false then the popup will be showed to user
If auth is true then nothing happens

I'm using Modal from the Material UI for popup, is slightly changed.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import "./popup.css";

export default function TransitionsModal(auth) {
    const [open,
        setOpen] = React.useState(auth);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500
            }}>
          <Fade in={open}>
                    <div className="popup-container" id='blur'>
                        <h1>Profil detaylarını görebilmek için lütfen giriş yapınız.</h1 >
                        <div className='popup-buttons'>
                            <a className='giris-yap-wrapper' href="/signIn">
                                <input
                                    type="submit"
                                    value="Giriş Yap"
                                    className="popup-input-login"
                                    onclick="togglePopup()"/>
                            </a>
                            <input type="submit" value="Vazgeç" className="popup-input" onClick={handleClose}/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fade>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and here is the code for profile card

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import './card.css';
import HeartButton from "./HeartButton";

import Modal from './Pop';



const Card = ({ profile, auth }) => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(auth);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setIsShown(auth);
    alert(isShown+  " "+ auth);
  }

  return (
    <div className='influencer-profile-card' onClick={handleClick}>
      {!isShown && <Modal auth={ !auth } />}
      <div>
        <HeartButton/>
      </div>

      <div className="profile_picture">
        <img src={profile.picture !== 'N/A' ? profile.picture : 'https://via.placeholder.com/400'} alt={profile.name} />
      </div>

      <div className="info">
        <h3>{profile.name}</h3>
        <h4>{profile.ID + " • " + profile.category}</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

The above code is only shows the popup at user's first visit. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I may have looked at this wrong.

You can pass the `auth` variable as a prop to the `Card` component, and use this prop to determine whether or not to show the modal. This way, the modal will be shown if `auth` is false, and hidden if `auth` is true.

In the `Card` component, update the Modal component to use the auth prop that you're passing in:

```
const Card = ({ profile, auth }) => {
  // You can remove the useState hook and isShown variable,
  // as you won't need them anymore
  // const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(auth);

  // You can also remove this handleClick function,
  // as you won't need it anymore
  // const handleClick = event => {
  //   setIsShown(auth);
  //   alert(isShown+  " "+ auth);
  // }

  return (
    <div className='influencer-profile-card' onClick={handleClick}>
      {/* Use the auth prop here to determine whether to show the modal or not */}
      {!auth && <Modal auth={ !auth } />}
      <div>
        <HeartButton/>
      </div>

      <div className="profile_picture">
        <img src={profile.picture !== 'N/A' ? profile.picture : 'https://via.placeholder.com/400'} alt={profile.name} />
      </div>

      <div className="info">
        <h3>{profile.name}</h3>
        <h4>{profile.ID + " • " + profile.category}</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Then, when you use the `Card` component, make sure to pass the `auth` variable as a prop:

```
<Card profile={profile} auth={auth} />
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, the popup still showed on at the first load of page no matter auth is true or false. Also later clicks don't work.

Comment: @questionhead I think I was going in the complete wrong direction - provided an updated response - I hope this helps.

Comment: The component Modal needs to be re-rendered every time the user clicks on the card and auth is true. Now <div className='influencer-profile-card' onClick={handleClick}> is unusable because of the handleClick.